# Arduino keeps disconnecting

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I've tried searching how to fix this on Google; however, I came to no resolve. Recently I've been working on a project, I originally had the code separated as a RFID reader and WAV player, but when I uploaded a merged version the Arduino Uno disconnected itself and will repeatedly do so. This is a problem seeming I am even unable to upload a blank sketch and try again. My guess is that it runs out of RAM and crashes. Is there a way to fix this ?

**EDIT:**

The problem only appears to occur with the Linux compiler

Answer (score 2):

The board could have insufficient power. To check this this, try removing all output cables. If the board works without the out-cables and stops working when you connect them, it's a power issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well i think arduino will keep on resetting if it ran out of RAM , but it wont disconnect it self. as per my experience with arduino when using different shields components and arduino keeps on resetting that would be due to a shortage in power. try to connect external power supply to your arduino , also try to let arduino work with out any shields connected to it, do you still notice the same behavior ?

Comment: The behaviour is the same, the only difference is when I power it via 5v battery it runs the code that was uploaded to it prior.